# Easy way to use a queue

Tags: python, list, data-structures, queue

I know a list can easily be used as a stack like here:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
a = l.pop()

print(f"{a=}")
print(f"{l=}")
```

Output:

```
a=3
l=[1, 2]
```

Is there an easy way to also get the first element, i.e. make a list function like a queue in Python?

I could write some short code like:

```
from typing import Any, List, Union

l = [1, 2, 3]

def dequeue(l: List[Any]) -> Union[List[Any], Any]:
    dequeued_element = l[0]
    new_list = l[1:]
    return new_list, dequeued_element

l, dequeued_element = dequeue(l)

print(f"{dequeued_element=}")
print(f"{l=}")
```

Output:

```
dequeued_element=1
l=[2, 3]
```

What I'm looking for is, if there is something builtin, just like the `.pop()` method in the python list?

Comment: Besides the `queue` standard-library module, you realize you can provide an index to `list.pop`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin `queue` module in python that should more than suffice.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html